# What is the correct SELECT to read different language text from a single file in Synapse SQL Serverless

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I have the following two rows in the `DimProductTest.csv`: https://pastebin.pl/view/cb8c749b

The following T-SQL query shows proper results if I only have the first row in the file but doesn't work if I have two rows. I tried removing all the `COLLATE` options and it still doesn't work.

```
SELECT
    TOP 100 * 
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK '/users/Raw/DropZone/DP203-awdata/DimProductTest.csv',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'GlobalDataLake',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'
    ) 
WITH (
    [ProductKey] [int],
    [ProductAlternateKey] [nvarchar](25),
    [ProductSubcategoryKey] [int],
    [WeightUnitMeasureCode] [nchar](3),
    [SizeUnitMeasureCode] [nchar](3),
    [EnglishProductName] [nvarchar](50),
    [SpanishProductName] [nvarchar](50),
    [FrenchProductName] [nvarchar](50),
    [StandardCost] [money],
    [FinishedGoodsFlag] [bit],
    [Color] [nvarchar](15),
    [SafetyStockLevel] [smallint],
    [ReorderPoint] [smallint],
    [ListPrice] [money],
    [Size] [nvarchar](50),
    [SizeRange] [nvarchar](50),
    [Weight] [float],
    [DaysToManufacture] [int],
    [ProductLine] [nchar](2),
    [DealerPrice] [money],
    [Class] [nchar](2),
    [Style] [nchar](2),
    [ModelName] [nvarchar](50),
    [LargePhoto] [varbinary](max),
    [EnglishDescription] [nvarchar](400),
    [FrenchDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE French_CI_AS,
    [ChineseDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS,
    [ArabicDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS,
    [HebrewDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS,
    [ThaiDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE Thai_CI_AS,
    [GermanDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS,
    [JapaneseDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI,
    [TurkishDescription] [nvarchar](400) COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS,
    [StartDate] [datetime],
    [EndDate] [datetime],
    [Status] [nvarchar](7)
)
AS [result]
```

Comment: My first thought is to suggest the docs about UTF-8 being recommended and tried that. I’m frankly not sure this is the fix but it’s worth a shot. Here is a blog post related to that. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/always-use-utf-8-collations-to-read-utf-8-text-in-serverless-sql/ba-p/1883633

Comment: Please don't use pastebin links to examples, in this case the link is already 404 file not found. By removing columns from the file and code you will both reduce the example to being a minimal reproducible example, such that you can include the example data directly in the question, but also potentially diagnose the cause yourself (if not the solution). Voting to close ad right now the question is impossible to answer and useless to all future readers.